# How to convert Numpy NaT values to Pandas datetime values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I need to convert `numpy.datetime64('NaT')` values to Pandas `datetime` values. I used Gord Thompson's solution below to convert `numpy.datetime64` values.

```
def dt64_to_datetime(dt64):
   unix_epoch = np.datetime64(0, 's')
   one_second = np.timedelta64(1, 's')
   seconds_since_epoch = (dt64 - unix_epoch) / one_second
   return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch)
```

Example usage:

```
for value in df[col].values: ##Convert each np.datetime64 value in DF column to Pandas datetime
    dt = dt64_to_datetime(value)
```

When the function reaches a `np.datetime64('NaT')` value, the following error is shown: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.`

**What can I do to convert** `np.datetime64('NaT')` **values to Python** `datetime` **values?**

---

**EDIT / UPDATE:**

I am trying to convert `np.datetime64('NaT')` values to Python `datetime` values because research has shown that this can help me upload the values from DataFrame column into MS Access table. **How can I do this?**

Comment: They are not pandas datetime values but are from the module `datetime`.  Question is why you want to convert in the first place and how do you plan to handle missing values in your code downstream (`NaT` = Not a Time).

Comment: @ Alexander - I meant converting `np.datetime64('NaT')` values to Python `datetime` values. I am planning to upload the values in Dataframe column into MS Access table.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Alexander's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411802/alexander) comment, it's best to explicitly handle null values. One way would be to edit your function like so:

```
import pandas as pd

def dt64_to_datetime(dt64):
    unix_epoch = np.datetime64(0, 's')
    one_second = np.timedelta64(1, 's')
    if pd.isnull(dt64):
        return pd.NaT
    else:
        seconds_since_epoch = (dt64 - unix_epoch) / one_second
        return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch)
```

On my environment `pd.isnull(numpy.datetime64('NaT'))` returns `True`. Also, my environment actually can't replicate your error (it returns `nan` without explicitly handling nulls). So consider upgrading pandas and / or numpy.

Comment: @ Ido S - Thank you for your comment. Question: I am trying to populate `NaT` values from pandas DataFrame into MS Access table. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Not sure -- I'm not familiar with MS Access. But you can just use something else instead of ````pd.NaT```` to handle nulls. For instance, if you chose just the number 0, or -1 (something to indicate that this is a null value).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a datetime.datetime analog for numpy.datetitme64('NaT').
Catch the error and just choose something appropriate. Since the error says the value is too large, return the maximum datetime possible.

```
def dt64_to_datetime(dt64):
    unix_epoch = np.datetime64(0, 's')
    one_second = np.timedelta64(1, 's')
    seconds_since_epoch = (dt64 - unix_epoch) / one_second
    #print(seconds_since_epoch)
    try:
        v = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch)
    except OSError as e:
        #print(e)
        v = datetime.datetime.max
    return v
```